# How to get Notice and Hint logs of vertica cli into a file

Tags: vertica, vsql

this is my vsql cli command. Trying to store memory data and time into an output file.

```
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U xxxx -d Xxxx --password='xxxx' --timing -c 'profile xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -o sample.log
vsql: warning: extra command-line argument "i" ignored
NOTICE 4788:  Statement is being profiled
HINT:  Select * from v_monitor.execution_engine_profiles where transaction_id=xxxxxxxxxxx and statement_id=xxx;
NOTICE 3557:  Initiator memory for query: [on pool general: Xxxxxx KB, minimum: XXXxx KB]
NOTICE 5077:  Total memory required by query: [Xxxxxx KB]
  count  
---------
 6344737
(1 row)
```

but in the sample.log file getting only:-

```
  count  
---------
 6344737
(1 row)

Time: First fetch (1 row): 547.649 ms. All rows formatted: 547.715 ms
```

how can I get Total memory required into the file.

I expect all results along with hint and notice command to be in one file

Comment: All fully detailed measures are in the `execution_engine_profiles` table. Select from it using the transaction id and statement id . Even the query is pasted onto the message: `Select * from v_monitor.execution_engine_profiles where transaction_id=xxxxxxxxxxx and statement_id=xxx;` No data reaches the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I need to apply this in order to get all the hints and notice messages:

```
$VSQLPATH -U $USERNAME -d $DB_NAME -w $PWD -h $HOST --timing -e -c "PROFILE $query" > $FILEPATH 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your vsql command to include the NOTICE messages in the output file by adding the -e option. This option will redirect all messages, including the NOTICE messages, to the output file. Here's the modified command:

bash
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U xxxx -d Xxxx --password='xxxx' --timing -c 'profile xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -e -o sample.log

Comment: This did not help in printing NOTICE logs in the file it gave output like this sample.log  `         
    count  
---------
 6344737
(1 row)
         `

Answer (score 0):

All fully detailed measures are in the `execution_engine_profiles`  table. Select from it using the transaction id and statement id . Even the query is pasted onto the message:
`Select * from v_monitor.execution_engine_profiles where transaction_id=xxxxxxxxxxx and statement_id=xxx;`

No data reaches the log file - or the report for that matter.